# Aspectj - intercept HTTP request

Tags: spring, http, aspectj, interceptor

Is it possible, using aspectj or other features in spring to intercept a HTTP request and then based on some logic return without executing the target method? I'm trying to create a wrapper around my web service for additional control, the web service is using the Jersey rest API so i cant use spring interceptors and a filter may not be able access the features i need.

Thanks

Comment: Why wouldn't a `javax.servlet.Filter` work? What sort of features are not accessible to a `Filter`? With `aspectj` it is of course possible, but over complicate stuff?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[AspectJ](http://eclipse.org/aspectj/) is intended for the cross-cutting of bytecode rather than for interception of HTTP requests.

A servlet filter is more appropriate for the interception of `Jersey` `REST` requests, in particular, one that implements [ContainerRequestFilter](http://jax-rs-spec.java.net/nonav/2.0-SNAPSHOT/apidocs/javax/ws/rs/container/ContainerRequestFilter.html). The following segment will be required in the `web.xml`:

```
<init-param>
  <param-name>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerRequestFilters</param-name>
  <param-value>my.package.to.MyFilterClass</param-value>
</init-param>
```

See [here](http://arnavawasthi.blogspot.ie/2011/09/writing-custom-filter-for-jersey.html) for more information